# Reading Clover data into a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The function below is populating the spreadsheet until it gets this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'elements')
getCloverSales  @ getCloverSales.gs:33

I can't seem to figure out how to trap the error and continue to get the range of records.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm a noob to javascript and I'm trying to wrap my brain around it.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

```
    function getCloverSales(startDate, endDate) {
      var startDate = "1675530917000"; // epoch unix format incl ms
      var endDate = "1676177999000";   // epoch unix format incl ms
      var API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx';
      var MERCHANT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
      var url = 'https://api.clover.com/v3/merchants/' + MERCHANT_ID + '/orders?filter=createdTime%3E' +       startDate + '&filter=createdTime%3C' + endDate + '&expand=lineItems&limit=1000&orderBy=createdTime';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + API_KEY
      
    }
  });
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(startDate);
    Logger.log(endDate);
    Logger.log(data);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sales Custom');
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.appendRow(['Date', 'Item Code', 'Item Name', 'Price', 'Order Ref']); // Write the header row
  for (var i = 0; i < data.elements.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(i);
    
    var order = data.elements[i];
    var lineItems = order.lineItems.elements;
        
        for (var j = 0; j < lineItems.length; j++) {
          Logger.log(j);
          Logger.log(lineItems);
          var lineItem = lineItems[j];
          var itemName = lineItem.name;
          var itemCode = lineItem.itemCode;
          var itemTime = lineItem.createdTime;
          var date = new Date(itemTime);
          var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'GMT-7:00', 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
          var price = lineItem.price / 100; // Convert from cents to dollars
          // var total = lineItem.total;
          var orderRef = lineItem.orderRef;
          sheet.appendRow([formattedDate, itemCode, itemName, price, orderRef]); // Write the sales item data into the sheet
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the value of `response.getContentText()` by removing your personal information?

Comment: I am not sure how to provide this as Google truncates the output as it's too large?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I am not sure how to provide this as Google truncates the output as it's too large?`, how about creating it as a text file with `DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", response.getContentText())`? But, unfortunately, I cannot know `it's too large`. So, if the size is much large, can you provide the simple sample value for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: {"href": "https://www.clover.com/v3/merchants/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/orders/GH0C2WEFTK0RR", "id": "GH0C2WEFTK0RR", "currency": "USD", "employee": {"id": "KAXTHTY8XPMEG"}, "total": 0, "paymentState": "OPEN", "title": "0018", "taxRemoved": false, "isVat": false, "state": "locked", "manualTransaction": false, "groupLineItems": true, "testMode": false, "payType": "FULL", "createdTime": 1675538163000, "clientCreatedTime": 1675538163000, "modifiedTime": 1675538376000, "device": {"id": "000001da-6d7a-3067-16b1-17c8b34d4bd1"}}

Comment: I believe that is the section where the error is exiting the script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested your script using your sample value, I cannot replicate your error of `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'elements')`. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'elements')`?

Comment: Thank you for replying.  Please see the whole txt file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xBa0d_qRviyZ22JyCv40vksss78KSYJ9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided sample value, I could correctly replicate your issue. So, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your provided sample value, I could find the reason for your current issue of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'elements')`. In your value, the element without the property of `lineItems` not existing. By this, it seems that such the error occurs.
- In your script, `appendRow` is used in a loop. In this csae, the process cost will be high. [Ref (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- I thought that `var orderRef = lineItem.orderRef;` might be `var orderRef = lineItem.orderRef.id;`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
sheet.appendRow(['Date', 'Item Code', 'Item Name', 'Price', 'Order Ref']); // Write the header row
for (var i = 0; i < data.elements.length; i++) {
  Logger.log(i);
  
  var order = data.elements[i];
  var lineItems = order.lineItems.elements;
      
      for (var j = 0; j < lineItems.length; j++) {
        Logger.log(j);
        Logger.log(lineItems);
        var lineItem = lineItems[j];
        var itemName = lineItem.name;
        var itemCode = lineItem.itemCode;
        var itemTime = lineItem.createdTime;
        var date = new Date(itemTime);
        var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'GMT-7:00', 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
        var price = lineItem.price / 100; // Convert from cents to dollars
        // var total = lineItem.total;
        var orderRef = lineItem.orderRef;
        sheet.appendRow([formattedDate, itemCode, itemName, price, orderRef]); // Write the sales item data into the sheet
  }
}
```

#### To:

```js
var ar = [['Date', 'Item Code', 'Item Name', 'Price', 'Order Ref']];
for (var i = 0; i < data.elements.length; i++) {
  if (!data.elements[i] || !data.elements[i].hasOwnProperty("lineItems") || !data.elements[i].lineItems.hasOwnProperty("elements")) continue;
  var temp = [];
  var order = data.elements[i];
  var lineItems = order.lineItems.elements;
  for (var j = 0; j < lineItems.length; j++) {
    var lineItem = lineItems[j];
    var itemName = lineItem.name;
    var itemCode = lineItem.itemCode;
    var itemTime = lineItem.createdTime;
    var date = new Date(itemTime);
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'GMT-7:00', 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    var price = lineItem.price / 100;
    var orderRef = lineItem.orderRef.id;
    temp.push([formattedDate, itemCode, itemName, price, orderRef]);
  }
  ar = [...ar, ...temp];
}
sheet.getRange(1, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much!  Your modification works and gets through 1000 order lines.  I am wondering however if I put in a date range of say an entire month how can I get all of the results if they exceed the Clover limit of 1000 items per api call?  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Rob Harris Thank you for replying. About `Wow thank you very much! Your modification works and gets through 1000 order lines.`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About your new question of `I am wondering however if I put in a date range of say an entire month how can I get all of the results if they exceed the Clover limit of 1000 items per api call?`, I would like to support you.